# track spotify playback using web controlls

Tags: spotify

Could you please help me this point

Is there any way to control track playback using web controlls for example I have

```
<a href="spotify:track:4bz7uB4edifWKJXSDxwHcs">play</a>
```

on my webpage 
is there a way to stop playback with something like

```
<a href="spotify:stop">stop</a>
```

go to next track with

```
<a href="spotify:next">next</a>
```

or something lke this or any other way

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible with Spotify Uri's, it is however possible to add the Spotify Play Button to your website, the Spotify Play Button supports songs, albums and playlists. You could also try to find out how it works and you might be able implement it  that way.

https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/spotify-play-button/

Comment: Thanks a lot, I know about button, but we wanted another design for our web part of player. 
Do you plan to add some open javascript API to work with spotify desctop app, as you do it inside "spitify play button" iframe?
Thanks ;)

Comment: I am not a Spotify employee, so I don't know if this API is planned. I have however looked into implementing this and I found out that you have to patch the Spotify client to work with a source other than the Spotify play button. I am not sure how to create this patch. This patch involves adding an entry to the local Spotify webserver, which always runs when Spotify is running, to allow API access from a site other than http://embed.spotify.com/. Another option is to create a 'helper', there are remotes available which use this. All in all, it is probably too involving :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a node module that may help!

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-spotify-webhelper

You can get the status of the Desktop Player and you can control it.

Pause, Play etc

I don't know if you can do next or prev I am trying to find myself for this.